# VBA Scripting Runtime Library with Unix file - LF as End Of Line instead of CRLF issue

Tags: vba

I'm writing a very simple parser to read text files into Excel.
Files are exceeding available lines in Excel 2012, so I have to go for a line by line approach.

I've tested Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library, TextStream Object and ReadLine method.

It works fine as far as I have Windows files with CRLF as end of line, while it fails when only LF is marking end of line.

I've seen lots of solutions outside VBA, is there any viable solution within VBA?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Start by making with a test file that uses only LFs as line endings in c:\temp\lfs.txt

This will read the file into a string:

```
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim sBuf As String
Dim sTemp As String

 FileNum = FreeFile
 Open "c:\temp\lfs.txt" For Input As FileNum

 While Not EOF(FileNum)
     Line Input #FileNum, sBuf
     sTemp = sTemp & sBuf
 Wend

 Close FileNum

' Now, what do we have?  First the string itself:
Debug.Print sTemp
' Are there any CRs in it?  
Debug.Print Replace(sTemp, vbCr, "CR")
' LFs?
Debug.Print Replace(sTemp, vbLf, "LF")
' Replace the LFs with CRLFs:
Debug.Print Replace(sTemp, vbLf, vbCrLf)

Now if you write it back out to file, you should be able to use it
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, this is a solution, I was hoping to find something that do not require to read entire text and write it again. My text files exceed easily 400MB, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following very simple text file separated by LFs. The following vba code workes for me. May be you could post short sample of your text file data where the TextStream.ReadLine method fails with?

[image]

```
Private Const TEXT_FILE_PATH As String = "C:\Temp\VBA\textFileForUnix.txt"

Public Sub test()
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    ReadText sheet:=targetSheet, textFilePath:=TEXT_FILE_PATH
End Sub

Private Sub ReadText(ByRef sheet As Worksheet, ByRef textFilePath As String)
    Dim scriptingFileSystem As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim scriptingFile As Scripting.File
    Dim scriptingStream As Scripting.TextStream

    Set scriptingFileSystem = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set scriptingFile = scriptingFileSystem.GetFile(textFilePath)

    Set scriptingStream = scriptingFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Byte
    With scriptingStream
        r = 1
        c = 1
        Do While Not .AtEndOfStream
          sheet.Cells(r, c).Value = .ReadLine
          r = r + 1
        Loop
       .Close
    End With

    Set scriptingFile = Nothing
    Set scriptingFileSystem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, sorry for the delay in answering but I had to go for a work around similar to what Steve above is suggesting. I have not solved the issue yet and your approach does nto seem to work. I could be wrong, though, so I'm attaching an example file (It is extracted from a 400MB file)

Comment: if there's a way to attach a file, though. I'm probably naive, but can't find a way.

Comment: @user2202749 No it is not possible to attach file to question. Use e.g. this server : http://www.filehosting.org/ and share the link here. I will download it to my pc then.

Comment: Thanks @user2202749; I have to excuse myself, but the code that Daniel Dusek has proposed looks good and it works, so I guess it was all my mistake and this question can be closed. Apologies for creating confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner will fix any "unusual" end-of-line I've ever came across to a proper CRLF. In particular it will fix either single LF's or single CR's or LF-CR's.

```
 result$ = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(txt$, vbLf & vbCr, vbLf), vbCrLf, vbLf), vbLf, vbCrLf), vbCr, vbCrLf), vbCrLf & vbLf, vbCrLf)
```